# Change positions (flip) two elements with css

Tags: html, css

I have the following `div` which contains an input and a label.

```
<div class="js-form-item ">

    <input  type="checkbox" id="checkboxes-11" class="type-checkboxes form-checkbox"> 

    <label for="option-a-checkboxes-11" class="option">
        Factures  11chf
    </label>

    <div class="option-price-style">  </div>
</div>
```

The input appears before the label, but I am trying to reverse the order so the label can appear before the input. I have tried do this making the input `display:block` and pulling it downward with `margin-bottom:1px` but it does not work

Comment: Can you not simply reverse the order?

Comment: It is generated by a CMS and it can't be done from there.

Comment: is this what you want https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/qzdpwv1L/1/

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/ddoq5mvv/1/

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can't reverse the order because your css looks somewhat like this:

```
input > label {}
```

There is a way to do this using flexbox though:

```
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
input {
  order: 2;
}
label {
  order: 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nzzqehog/2/

Comment: They are side by side. I tried to do display:block, width:100% for each of the elements but it does not work

Comment: You can see in the fiddle that it doesn't work. They are side by side

Comment: And what is the problem with having it side by side? Just change the flexbox to a column layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you set them to `float: right` they will appear in reverse order.

If that doesn't give the desired result because, for example, you want them to be stacked vertically, you can use margin or padding to alter the positions of the elements.

Comment: Nope, the label is not flipped. It's still at the bottom